# Round a value to nearest number divisible by 2, 4, 8 and 16?

Tags: python

How do i round a decimal number to the nearest number divisible by 2, 4, 8 and 16 in python?

Example:

```
1920/1.33 = 1443.609022556391
```

It should round off to 1440 as it is easily divisible by the 2, 4, 8 and 16 and vice versa ( 1440*1.33 = 1920 ).

```
1920/1.33 = 1440
```

Comment: Why not just even numbers? Or do you want to find the nearest power of two?

Comment: Isn't every number divisible by _2, 4, 8 or 16_ divisible by _2_? Doesn't that make the question "_how to round to the nearest even number_"?

Comment: @BartvanNierop: The question says *2, 4, 8 **and** 16*, which is just numbers divisible by 16.

Comment: Well due to specific needs, i 'm working on a personal project related to computer display resolutions.

Comment: @Blckknght It didn't when I wrote the comment.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What about `int( 16 * round( value / 16. ))` ?

Comment: Possibly with `math.floor()` instead of `round()`?

Comment: Possibly with any tweak that anybody wants ; that's what programming is for : do exactly what we want ! :) However the OP said "round to the nearest number", and that's just what `round` does.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but this question is not exactly a paragon of clarity.

Comment: The question states to round to the nearest multiple of 16 so `round()` is better because it will round up at the appropriate point e.g. compare when value is 23 then 24. Using `round()` will round up at 24 whereas `math.floor()` returns 16 for `16 <= value < 32`. Behaviour around 0 is ambiguous - is 0 divisible by 16? `round()` also behaves as you'd expect for negative numbers (although negatives and 0 wouldn't normally be considered multiples).

Answer (score 8):

If a number is divisible by 16, then it is divisible by 2, 4 and 8. Knowing this, just compute the modulo 16 remainder of the decimal number and substract it from the base number.

```
>>>> 1443.609022556391 - (1443.609022556391 % 16)
1440.0
```

Comment: Great idea, but it is somehow biased towards smaller values. For example: ```15331 - (15331 % 3) -> 15330``` and ```15332 - (15332 % 3) -> 15330```. Using ```round```, however, ```15331 -> 15330``` but ```15332 ->15333```.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a solution without division and rounding function, here is a simple one:

```
def round16(a):
    return int(a) + 8 & ~15
```

Example:

```
>>> [(x/2, round16(x/2)) for x in range(64)]
[(0.0, 0), (0.5, 0), (1.0, 0), (1.5, 0), (2.0, 0), (2.5, 0), (3.0, 0), (3.5, 0),
(4.0, 0), (4.5, 0), (5.0, 0), (5.5, 0), (6.0, 0), (6.5, 0), (7.0, 0), (7.5, 0),
(8.0, 16), (8.5, 16), (9.0, 16), (9.5, 16), (10.0, 16), (10.5, 16), (11.0, 16), (11.5, 16),
(12.0, 16), (12.5, 16), (13.0, 16), (13.5, 16), (14.0, 16), (14.5, 16), (15.0, 16),
(15.5, 16), (16.0, 16), (16.5, 16), (17.0, 16), (17.5, 16), (18.0, 16), (18.5, 16),
(19.0, 16), (19.5, 16), (20.0, 16), (20.5, 16), (21.0, 16), (21.5, 16), (22.0, 16),
(22.5, 16), (23.0, 16), (23.5, 16), (24.0, 32), (24.5, 32), (25.0, 32), (25.5, 32),
(26.0, 32), (26.5, 32), (27.0, 32), (27.5, 32), (28.0, 32), (28.5, 32), (29.0, 32),
(29.5, 32), (30.0, 32), (30.5, 32), (31.0, 32), (31.5, 32)]
```